# Is it possible to achieve this layout only with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to achieve this layout with raw bootstrap but for the life of me I can not figure it out.

Been throu a few iterations so my markup is very far from complete but I am hoping the picture will provide experianced front-enders enough information.

```
 <style>
    .potato{
        background:blue;
        border:1px solid black;
        height:400px;
    }
    .paprika{
        background:red;
        border:1px solid black;
        height:1200px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 paprika">
            Long box

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 potato">
            short box

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[Picture of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAPsb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could possibly be done with bootstrap grids (Ref. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), see the example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid for some code to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here's a [PEN](https://codepen.io/sebaLinares/pen/RvVRoM)

```
<div class="container cont">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="any col-md-4 green">
      <div class="div-cont"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="any col-md-4 green">
      <div class="div-cont"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="any col-md-4 green">
      <div class="div-cont"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="any col-md-6 green">
          <div class="div-cont"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="any col-md-6 green">
          <div class="div-cont"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="any col-md-6 green">
          <div class="div-cont"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="any col-md-6 green">
          <div class="div-cont"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="any col-md-6 green">
          <div class="div-cont"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="any col-md-6 green">
          <div class="div-cont"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 big">
      <div class="div-cont-dif"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have yo play with your CSS if you want it to be JUST like the one in your photo, but that's the general idea, a row inside a col-md-8. The extra classes are just for colors and sizes, the layout is all bootstrap

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.row` with `.no-gutters` and adjust the paddings for `container` class.

**Working version**: https://codepen.io/cdtapay/pen/wNdWXb?editors=1100